# Combobox-based map editor in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Heh, the title must sound dreadful and noobish

Anyway, I'm working on a simple web game that's basically a labyrinth. To make a map I have to manually write coordinates of walls, and I thought it'd speed up the development process greatly if I'd make a map editor. The first thing that came to my mind was python's tkinter generating a grid of combo boxes.

The grid is generated fine, but I have problems with exporting the "map". I think each combobox has to have an unique text variable and a way to check it's coordinates. I thought I'd solve both problems if I'd set the variable's name to its coordinates, but I don't think it's working and I don't know how to access the values later on. Here's the important bit of the code (sorry for not showing everything right away, but StackOverflow's formatting is horrible when posting python):

```
def scale(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.width.set(self.setwidth.get())
    self.height.set(self.setheight.get())
    name=[0,0]
    while name[0]<=(self.width.get() - 1) and name[1]<=self.height.get():
        n=(str(name[0]) + ',' + str(name[1]))
        o={'name': n}
        self.o['name']=tk.StringVar()
        self.n=ttk.Combobox(self, textvariable=o['name'], values=('F', 'W', 'V', 'S'), width=1, state='readonly')
        self.n.grid(column=name[0], row=(name[1] + 1))
        self.n.set('V')
        print self.o['name'].get()
        if name[0]==(self.width.get() - 1) and name[1]<self.height.get():
            name[0]=0
            name[1]=name[1]+1
        else:
            name[0]=name[0]+1
    self.update()
```

The code above gives me the `App instance has no attribute 'o'`... what can I do about it? Can it even be done?

Thanks!

Comment: It's usually helpful to post the full exception trace so it's easy to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when you write `self.o['name']`, `self` (which I assume is the instance of `App` in question) has not been given an `o` attribute.

I suspect that the line before that, where you write `o={'name': n}`, you really mean to write `self.o={'name': n}`, which would fix that immediate problem.